# Why does C++11 contain an odd clause about comparing void pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, language-lawyer, comparison-operators

While checking the references for another question, I noticed an odd clause in C++11, at [expr.rel] ¶3:

> Pointers to `void` (after pointer conversions) can be compared, with a result defined as follows: If both
>   pointers represent the same address or are both the null pointer value, the result is `true` if the operator is
>   `<=` or `>=` and `false` otherwise; otherwise the result is unspecified.

This seems to mean that, once two pointers have been casted to `void *`, their ordering relation is no longer guaranteed; for example, this:

```
int foo[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
void *a = &foo[0];
void *b = &foo[1];
std::cout<<(a < b);
```

would seem to be unspecified.

Interestingly, this clause wasn't there in C++03 and disappeared in C++14, so if we take the example above and apply the C++14 wording to it, I'd say that ¶3.1

> - If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher subscript compares greater.

would apply, as `a` and `b` point to elements of the same array, even though they have been casted to `void *`. Notice that the wording of ¶3.1 was there pretty much the same in C++11, but seemed to be overridden by the `void *` clause.

Am I right in my understanding? What was the point of that oddball clause added in C++11 and immediately removed? Or maybe it's still there, but moved to/implied by some other part of the standard?

Comment: It's not odd, C and C++ are typed languages, assigning the address of an integer array to void* isn't a like for like assignment therefore a cast is required.  static_cast<void*>(foo);

Comment: @SPlatten: any data pointer has an implicit conversion to `void *`, so no explicit cast is required, although it's true that on some odd architectures (segmented memory comes to mind) casting to `void *` may not be a plain bitwise copy; still, I cannot imagine an architecture where the "regular pointer" to "big, `void` pointer" conversion wouldn't preserve the ordering relation between elements of the same array.

Comment: I could image pointer comparison being implemented as "count the number of elements between a and b; if it's negative then b<a". That won't work for `void*` of course, as there's no `void[]`.

Comment: @MSalters: I can also imagine `a - b` being implemented as `int c; while((c = rand()) + b == a);`, but that doesn't mean it's anywhere near sensible. :-) Also, I'd expect it to violate the time complexity requirements stated somewhere in the algorithms/containers section.

Comment: According to the wording of that clause `char c; bool b = (void *)&c == (void *)&c` would be false, against all reason. Am I reading it correctly?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I believe you are reading it incorrectly, here the standard is talking only about relational operators (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`), equality operators are discussed in the following section ([expr.eq]), which guarantees that the result of your expression is indeed `true` (_Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address (3.9.2)._)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ah, thanks. Don't have the standard here.

Comment: Right, what the standard is getting at here is that `x<=y` on voids has the semantics of `x==y||x<y`; if the left side is true, then the result is definitely true and that's well-defined. If the left side is false, then we're in undefined behaviour territory; there's no guarantee that void pointers are ordered in any consistent way. My opinion is that this is yet another "gotcha"; the developer who writes `<=` clearly does not have in their head "either equality or UB".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- in C++98/03 the clause was not present, and the standard did not specify relational operators for `void` pointers (core issue 879, see end of this post);
- the odd clause about comparing `void` pointers was added in C++11 to resolve it, but this in turn gave rise to two other core issues 583 & 1512 (see below);
- the resolution of these issues required the clause to be removed and be replaced with the wording found in C++14 standard, which allows for "normal" `void *` comparison.

---

Core Issue 583: [Relational pointer comparisons against the null pointer constant](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#583)

> 583. Relational pointer comparisons against the null pointer constant Section: 8.9  [expr.rel]
>
> In C, this is ill-formed (cf C99 6.5.8):
>
> ```
> void f(char* s) {
>     if (s < 0) { }
> } ...but in C++, it's not. Why? Who would ever need to write (s > 0) when they could just as well write (s != 0)?
> ```
>
> This has been in the language since the ARM (and possibly earlier);
>   apparently it's because the pointer conversions (7.11 [conv.ptr]) need
>   to be performed on both operands whenever one of the operands is of
>   pointer type. So it looks like the "null-ptr-to-real-pointer-type"
>   conversion is hitching a ride with the other pointer conversions.
>
> Proposed resolution (April, 2013):
>
> This issue is resolved by the resolution of **issue 1512**.

Core Issue 1512: [Pointer comparison vs qualification conversions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1512)

> 1512. Pointer comparison vs qualification conversions Section: 8.9  [expr.rel]
>
> According to 8.9 [expr.rel] paragraph 2, describing pointer
>   comparisons,
>
> Pointer conversions (7.11 [conv.ptr]) and qualification conversions
>   (7.5 [conv.qual]) are performed on pointer operands (or on a pointer
>   operand and a null pointer constant, or on two null pointer constants,
>   at least one of which is non-integral) to bring them to their
>   composite pointer type. This would appear to make the following
>   example ill-formed,
>
> ```
>  bool foo(int** x, const int** y) {
>  return x < y;  // valid ?   } because int** cannot be converted to const int**, according to the rules of 7.5 [conv.qual] paragraph 4.
> ```
>
> This seems too strict for pointer comparison, and current
>   implementations accept the example.
>
> Proposed resolution (November, 2012):

---

Relevant excerpts from **resolution of the above issues** are found in the paper: [Pointer comparison vs qualification conversions (revision 3)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3624.html).

> *The following also resolves core **issue 583**.*
>
> Change in 5.9 expr.rel paragraphs 1 to 5:

In this section the following statement (the ***odd clause in C++11***) has been **expunged**:

> Pointers to `void` (after pointer conversions) can be compared, with a result defined as follows: If both pointers represent the same address or are both the null pointer value, the result is `true` if the operator is `<=` or `>=` and `false` otherwise; otherwise the result is unspecified

And the following statements have been **added**:

> - If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher subscript compares greater.
> - If one pointer points to an element of an array, or to a subobject thereof, and another pointer points one past the last element of the array, the latter pointer compares greater.

So in the final working draft of **C++14** (n4140) section [expr.rel]/3, the above statements are found as they were stated at the time of the resolution.

---

Digging for the reason why this odd clause was added led me to a much earlier issue 879: [Missing built-in comparison operators for pointer types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#879).
The proposed resolution of this issue (in July, 2009) led to the addition of this clause which was voted into WP in October, 2009.

And that is how it came to be included in the C++11 standard.

Comment: This explains why it was removed, but why was it added in first place? What was the committee trying to achieve by restricting the comparison of `void *`? Or I am mistaken and the example in my question results in unspecified behavior on current-day C++ (IOW they just changed the wording)?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I tried to hunt for the reason why it was added by looking up the "Compatibility with C++03" section in the C++11 standard but could not find anything related mentioned. Current day C++(17) also does not mention this clause in any form (as far as I could check the standard), so the behavior may just be unspecified.

Comment: The "oddball clause" was unrelated to either core issue. It's more of a drive-by fix as the issue resolution rewrote the subclause.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Please see edit to the answer which answers the question why this odd clause was added in the first place.

Comment: @P.W: aaah, that's interesting! So, previously the clause wasn't there, but the previous wording just excluded completely `void *` from the allowed types for relational operators. C++11 added a first patch to this, to allow at least comparisons for `<=` and `>=` to be coherent with the `==` operator, and C++14 saw that this distinction was more trouble than it was worth, and gave all relational operators "regular" semantics even for void pointers. Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: While it is generally difficult to speculate the motivation behind the addition/deletion of patches to the standard, in this case I think you are correct. With the introduction of the `<=>` operator in C++20, I wonder how the semantics are going to be defined with respect to pointers.

Comment: @P.W: perfect, great detective work! When you happen to have a moment I think it would be best to add these new findings to the "tl;dr" at the top, then I'll be glad to accept your answer!

Comment: Yet, I'm still a bit dubious... the new wording defines the relational operators only for "pointers to objects" ("Comparing pointers to objects is defined as follows" C++14, [expr.rel], ¶3), but are `void *` considered pointers to objects? There's something about that at [basic.compound] ¶3, but I cannot make much sense of it.

Comment: "The type of a pointer to `void` or a pointer to an object type is called an _object pointer type_. [ _Note:_ A pointer to `void` does not have a pointer-to-object type, however, because void is not an object type. — _end note_ ] The type of a pointer that can designate a function is called a _function pointer type._ A pointer to objects of type `T` is referred to as a “pointer to `T`.” [ _Example:_ a pointer to an object of type `int` is referred to as “pointer to `int` ” and a pointer to an object of class `X` is called a “pointer to `X`.” — _end example_ ]" What is the note saying?

Comment: The note which should have made the preceding statement clearer seems to have made it more confusing. I wanted to see what the compiler thought of `void*` and used [`is_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) on `void*` and it evaluates to `true`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2cfff1ba17336e9.

Comment: `is_pointer` checks whether T is a **pointer to object** or a pointer to function (but not a pointer to member/member function) and provides the member constant value which is equal to true, if T is a object/function pointer type. Otherwise, value is equal to false.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Updated the TL;DR section.

Comment: @P.W: I rewrote the TL;DR section to make the steps a bit more explicit and to the point; feel free to edit/revert it if you don't like it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: The flow looks *more* structured now. Thanks for the edit.